# Missing neq symbol when using kpfonts package

Tags: packages, kpfonts, lmodern

I found out that when using package `kpfonts` my `\neq` symbol dissapears.

**I have to use package `lmodern` so that `kpfonts` does not kill my document**

### MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{kpfonts}% <-- comment and the symbol appears
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
$p$ y $q$ son enteros, $q \neq 0$.
\end{document}
```

Does anybody else have this problem? Should I stop using `kpfonts`? Is it possible to use `kpfonts` without `lmodern`?

### Extra info

I am using **TeXnicCenter** on Windows with **MikTeX**

- MikTeX v.2.9
- Output profile: LaTeX => PS => PDF

Comment: If I remove the calls to `amssymb`, `amsfonts` and `lmodern`, I get the expected `\neq` symbol.

Comment: It' not only possible to use kpfonts without lmodern, but recommended – unless you like conflicts…

Comment: Your example works fine here, the `\neq` shows up. Recently updated TeX Live 2016.